# Cloud SQL Federated Queries - Private Database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud, private-network

It is clear from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) that Federated queries are not possible from a private ip database
What can be the most GCP appropriate workarounds on this?

Comment: Not ideal but would you be able to just replicate the data from Cloud SQL to BigQuery?  Products like Fivetran or Debezium can keep the platforms in sync allowing you to query from BigQuery.  But ultimately the lack of a public IP is a limitation currently.

Comment: Thank you! Well this is my workaround currently.